# Instagram infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, instagram

I'm trying to use the Instagram infinite scroll found here:

https://github.com/DDKnoll/Instagram-Infinite-Scroll

Works fine, except in IE.  I think it has something to do with the following code:

```
//Infinite Scroll Window Bindings.
var infiniteScrollBinding = function(){

$(window).scroll(function(evt){
//Calculate Window Values on every scroll event.
var bod = $('body')[0];
pageHeight = bod.offsetHeight;
bottomScroll = window.scrollY + bod.clientHeight;
distanceToBottom = pageHeight - bottomScroll;


//Load more posts as needed.
if(distanceToBottom < 200){
  insta.load('after');
}
else if(window.scrollY <= 0){
  insta.load('before');
}
});
}
```

bod.offsetHeight always stays the same value in IE, while it changes dynamically with page scroll in other browsers.  Anyone know why?  Here is my copy of the code:

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Had to replace window.scrollY with window.pageYOffset.